# Run Scrapy on iOS/Pythonista?

Tags: python, ios, iphone, scrapy, pythonista

Is it possible to run scrapy on iOS with something like Pythonista?
My script works on my pc but I would like to start it from my iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with scrapy, but if the library is "pure python" then you should be able to install it and use it with Pythonista.  Pure python apparently means that the library cannot require any c-libraries.

You'd need some method of invoking pip to install the library, something like [StaSH](https://github.com/ywangd/stash) would work.  From there you can use pip to install the scrapy library.

No guarantees, but aside from the "pure python" bit, there's no reason it shouldn't work.